# How do I access Shopify data without advanced account?

Tags: shopify, liquid

All I'm wanting to do is track sales of certain products from a certain date. My company is wanting to add a banner to track sales goals for raising money for charities. So basically, we'd tag a few products as being part of that goal, set a goal, and then need to update the goal progress by a certain amount every time a sale is made on one of those products. As far as I can tell, without access to Shopify's analytics API, this is not possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to build is perfectly possible. However, you need to generate Private App Credentials, so you can use Shopify API. It doesn't matter if you have an account by *yourself*, someone else can follow [these steps](https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/api-credentials#generate-private-app-credentials) and send you the credentials your way.

If you don't actually need to modify anything through the API, you could have them set a webhook (Settings -> Notifications -> Webhook) on Order Creation (or similar) that posts to your server and you can check what product got sold and see if it has got the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The "easy" way to do this is to create an app that receives order webhooks and can check on tagged products and keep a sum of target items sold.

Then the app should have use a script tag to insert a simple script with the current value into the web page at a configured place by css selector
 OR the app could update one or more snippet files that you could include until the promo is done.

I'd tend to go with the script tag option since that's a bit more flexible and you should be able to change your theme when the promo is over to report results without having to touch the app again.